# How to modify the JPanel size in run time Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jpanel

i am trying to modify the JPanel size when i maximize the window.

The event is working correctly, but the new size doesn´t work.

```
private void resize(String type){
    if(type.equals("maximized")){
        System.out.println(panel_menu.getLocation());
        panel_menu.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(panel_menu.getWidth(), d.height));
        panel_menu.revalidate();
    }
}
```

That is what the panel is doing it when i maximize the window, but the JPanel doesn´t change the size when i click on the maximize button.

Any help? Thank you!

Comment: You state that your code "isn't working" but need to tell how it's not working. You will also want to present code in your question that we can compile, run, test and modify, a [mre] -- please read the important link as it will tell the details of this useful construct.

Comment: Sorry but i thought that i was being specific. The panel doesn´t change the size when i click on the maximize button. Thats the problem...

Comment: You do know that you're calling `revalidate()` on the component, not the container that holds it -- and this is what you should be doing. But again, you've still not posted a valid [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You generally *don't* modify the JPanel size directly but rather

- Use a smart combination of layout managers and nested JPanels that do the sizing for you
- Sometimes override `public Dimension getPreferredSize()` on the JPanel to allow it to *smartly* size itself, but doing so with care, and usually respecting the `super.getPreferredSize()` results in your override.

Comment: I am new with java swing, how can i do that?

Comment: @LuisBermúdez: do what? use the layout managers? Read the [Layout Manager Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html). Override getPreferredSize? -- read the relevant API for the method as well as similar questions on this site. Side note that your question is somewhat anemic in key details and code, including what exact effect you're trying to achieve, how your current code is not working. You will want to create and post a valid [mre] as well as check out the [ask] to help you improve the current and your future questions. Luck.

Comment: @LuisBermúdez for instance, if you place the JPanel into the JFrame's contentPane (which uses a BorderLayout) in the `BorderLayout.CENTER` position, then the JPanel will re-size directly with the JFrame. The key is to learn the various layout managers and then to experiment with them.